# Getting error message "Incorrect syntax near '(' " when running this query

Tags: sql-server

Trying to create a pivot table to display the  policy name and number of customers taken each policies in the year 2000, 2001, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2008, 2010, 2012, 2015

```
Select NAME, [2000], [2001], [2004], [2005], [2006], [2008], [2010], [2012], [2015] 
  from (
          select policy.name, year(customer_policy.policy_start_date) 
            from policy 
            join customer_policy 
              on policy.id = customer_policy.policy_id 
        group by policy.name, customer_policy.policy_start_date
       ) as SourceTable
  PIVOT
      (
      count(policy.name) for year(customer_policy.policy_start_date) 
        in ([2000], [2001], [2004], [2005], [2006], [2008], [2010], [2012], [2015])
       ) As PivotTable;
```

I am getting:

```
Incorrect syntax near '('
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need column aliases and some summarization:

```
Select NAME , [2000], [2001], [2004], [2005], [2006], [2008], [2010], [2012], [2015]
from (select p.name, year(cp.policy_start_date) as yr
      from policy p join
           customer_policy cp
           on p.id = cp.policy_id
      group by p.name, cp.policy_start_date
     ) as SourceTable
PIVOT (count(*)) for yr in ( [2000], [2001], [2004], [2005], [2006], [2008], [2010], [2012], [2015] ) ) As PivotTable
```

Comment: There is syntax errors but on resolving all those getting the result.

Comment: But need to get '0' instead of null when no value exists

Comment: @himanshu add to select list `Select NAME , coalesce([2000],0), coalesce([2001],0) ...`

Comment: Select NAME, isNull([2000],0) as [2000], isNull([2001],0) as [2001],.....